# $(...).autocomplete is not a function error

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following files

```
<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/boostrap-min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

Then I have javascript function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
            $("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
                source: '@Url.Action("MerrBarkodet","Produktet")'
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

But is not working, is showing error 
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Produktet", FormMethod.Get, new { @class = "navbar-form navbar-left" }))
    {
    <div class="form-group">
        <b>Search:</b>@Html.TextBox("search", null, new { id = "txtSearch" })
        <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Search" />
    </div>
    }
```

Comment: Could you please confirm whether `jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js` is loaded before your `$(document).ready` function?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao anything as a callback in document ready will be executed only after complete page load. excluding ajax load

Comment: #Sagar V.. That doesn't matter if the jqueryui is 404...

Comment: Yes, it is loaded before!

Comment: Can you change jQuery UI's script tag to `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>` and retry?

Comment: @31piy It's still same

Answer (score 2):

Comment out (or remove) the code I commented below. `$(function() { })` is not going to initialize inside a `$(document).ready()` call.

```
 //$(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
            $("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
                source: '@Url.Action("MerrBarkodet","Produktet")'
            });
        });
 //   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible causes for the issue.

1. The order that jquery.js get loaded. jquery.js must be present before jqueryui.js
2. Possible duplicate of jquery.js reference. Ensure that there is no jquery reference in your file. If you are implementing a layout file,or an external library ensure there is no jquery called there.
3. try using the jQuery.noConflict() method for a test. It basically just makes you use a different alias for jQuery.
   Ex:

   ```
   var j = jQuery.noConflict();
   j("div p").hide();
   ```
4. Check that you're function call isn't getting hit before the document is loaded:

   ```
   $(function(){
      var $searchBox = $('#txtSearch');
      $searchBox.autocomplete(...);
   });
   ```